# Dynamic DNS with tunnel/proxy to the public?

Tags: dns, proxy, tunnel, hostname, dynamic-dns

#### TL;DR:

I want to be able to access my laptop publicly from anywhere, while my laptop could also be anywhere. Any Service, any port.

#### Original Post:

I want to be able to access my own computer from a public domain so I can test OAuth integrations.

Setting up a CNAME record on my domain to point to my work address and forwarding ports to my computer is easy enough.

I move around a lot, and would still like to be able to publicly access my own computer.

I've looked into Dynamic DNS solutions, such as noip.com, but they require port forwarding. They are nice if I'm behind the same router all the time, but I am not.

So, I think I need some sort of tunnel or proxy service that will allow my computer to always be publicly available.

I tried searching for things like Dynamic DNS Tunnel, and it didn't seem like any services were easy to set up, or wouldn't clear that they would solve the problem I have.
Ideally, I'd like to just have a program on my computer that connects to the proxy or tunnel, and point my domain at that.

I also wonder if it's possible to have something in Ruby create a tunnel, and host that on my Site5.com account (or maybe another language Site5 is capable of running, idk, I'd have to look into that)... I wouldn't need to pay for anything extra then.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking for, you seem to be linking DNS to a lot of functionality.  Can you simplify the question, and describe the computers, and networks, and what *services* you're trying to connect to from where?

Comment: I added a TL;DR:

Comment: http://pagekite.net/

Comment: From what I've seen, there are 2 ways when you don't control the router/gateway/firewall, if you control the server and client, you can establish a P2P/VPN network and talk through that and that will break through NAT. But if you want to allow arbitrary public internet clients to communicate with your server (like just a plain old HTTP request), you need to establish a third party tunnel that is connected between the server the public internet, and connect to that instead from your client. A combination of DDNS and ngrok can help with this.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand... You want all that, without purchasing a static IP. Hence dynamic DNS...since the IP will be changing all the time. Then you make all your urls relative to the domain name and let the dynamic DNS handle the changing IP. I don't think you even need any internet side forwarding. Just across your router from ISP IPs to your LAN IPs.